# Firebase Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

i want to send users notification when they are being sent friend request using firebase cloud messaging, but when the request is sent it returns this error in firebase function log

> Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)

this is the java-script code i am using

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
 const user_id = context.params.user_id;
 const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

 console.log('We Have A Notification for :', user_id);

 if (!change.after.val()){
  return console.log("A Notification Has Been Deleted From The Database: ", notification_id)
 }

 const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

 return deviceToken.then(result => {

  const token_id = result.val();

  const payload = {
   notification: {
    title: "Friend Request",
    body: "You just got a new friend request",
    icon: "default"
   }
  };
 
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload ).then(Response =>{
 
   console.log('this is the notification')
  });
 

 });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `token_id` is `null` or an empty string. Most likely that's because `/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}` doesn't exist in your database, for example when there is no token for the targeted user.

To prevent the error message, simply check if the snapshot exists before using its value:

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

return deviceToken.then(result => {
    if (!result.exists() || result.val() === "") return false;

    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Friend Request",
            body: "You just got a new friend request",
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload ).then(Response =>{ 
        console.log('this is the notification')
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you might be storing an empty string in your database, so I just added a clause for that. Note that it's important you understand why this happens, so check your database for empty tokens and decide whether that is a normal use-case for your app. If so, make sure all your code deals with it correctly, not just when an error shows up like it did here.

Comment: i have checked my database and all the users have a device token stored. do you need a screen shot of my database?

Comment: i need someone to slap me right now. i just found my silly mistake, i was pointing to a wrong path

Answer (score 1):

after many wasted hours i got to discover what was wrong. now the issue was that i was pointing to the wrong path. this line of code was the issue

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
```

it was supposed to be this

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
```